# debian wifi connection keeps dropping and establishing

Tags: debian, wifi, iwlwifi

My wifi connection keeps dropping and establishing with 1 second periods for 5 minutes or so, in a random moment in the day.

Here is the `dmesg` output:

```
(the same output produced million times)

[70482.745053] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[70483.465934] wlan0: authenticate with 10:c6:1f:81:2a:3a
[70483.467539] wlan0: send auth to 10:c6:1f:81:2a:3a (try 1/3)
[70483.469346] wlan0: authenticated
[70483.469540] wlan0: associate with 10:c6:1f:81:2a:3a (try 1/3)
[70483.472719] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 10:c6:1f:81:2a:3a (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[70483.474643] wlan0: associated
[70484.184946] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[70484.906096] wlan0: authenticate with 10:c6:1f:81:2a:3a
[70484.907572] wlan0: send auth to 10:c6:1f:81:2a:3a (try 1/3)
[70484.909345] wlan0: authenticated
[70484.910712] wlan0: associate with 10:c6:1f:81:2a:3a (try 1/3)
[70484.913949] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 10:c6:1f:81:2a:3a (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[70484.915895] wlan0: associated
```

I tried to remove `iwlwifi` driver:

```
ceremcem@cca-erik:~$ sudo modprobe -rf iwlwifi 
modprobe: FATAL: Module iwlwifi is in use.
```

Maybe heavy usage of wifi connection causes this.

How can I find the exact reason of this problem? Here is the system information:

```
$ readlink /sys/class/net/wlan0/device/driver
../../../../bus/pci/drivers/iwlwifi

$ lspci -vq | grep -i wireless -B 1 -A 5

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 64
    Memory at c0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
$ uname -a
Linux cca-erik 3.13-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.13.10-1 (2014-04-15) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced the same problems some days ago.

There was this commit http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/linux-firmware.git/
updating intel 7260 firmware.

Comment: And did that fix it? Could you edit your answer and explain 1) whether this update fixed the issue and 2) exactly how it can be applied?